# Webpack bundling but not resolving typescript from node_modules package

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, webpack-4

Question guys, I've tried about every different way I can think of to solve this.

We have two folders in a makeshift **mono-repo** (no yarn workspace). One called **Mgt-Shared** one called **Server**. We reference shared from Servers `package.json` with `"mgt-shared": "file:../mgt-shared"`, and I run a simple `npm install` to get our shared into Servers `node_modules`.
Both projects are mixed typescript and javascript.
When I run webpack to attempt to bundle server, it works fine, the Typescript files from shared show up in the bundle list but when I run the `node dist/app.bundle.js` - it can't resolve some of the modules (specifically all the typescript ones).
When I run `webpack --json` I find this (which seems like it's resolving properly):

```
    {
      "id": "mgt-shared/discounts/discount_reasons",
      "identifier": "external \"mgt-shared/discounts/discount_reasons\"",
      "name": "external \"mgt-shared/discounts/discount_reasons\"",
      "index": 23,
      "index2": 15,
      "size": 42,
      "built": true,
      "optional": false,
      "prefetched": false,
      "chunks": [
        "main"
      ],
    ...
      "failed": false,
      "errors": 0,
      "warnings": 0,
      "assets": [],
      "reasons": [
        {
          "moduleId": "./src/discounts/discount.ts",
          "moduleIdentifier": "/home/mygastank/WebstormProjects/mygastank/server/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!/home/mygastank/WebstormProjects/mygastank/server/src/discounts/discount.ts",
          "module": "./src/discounts/discount.ts",
          "moduleName": "./src/discounts/discount.ts",
          "type": "cjs require",
          "userRequest": "mgt-shared/discounts/discount_reasons",
          "loc": "20:24-72"
        },
        {...
      ],
      "providedExports": null,
      "optimizationBailout": [],
      "depth": 6
    },
```

My webpack config is this:

```
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  target: 'node',
  // This forces resolution of native node modules
  externals: [nodeExternals({ modulesFromFile: true })],
  entry: './src/index',
  output: {
    filename: 'app.bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.json'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
      // Include ts, tsx, js, and jsx files.
      test: /\.(ts|js)?$/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      include: [/node_modules\/mgt-shared/],
      exclude: [/node_modules/],
      options: {
        presets: [
          [
            'env',
            {
              'targets': {
                'node': 'current'
              }
            }
          ],
          ['@babel/preset-typescript',
            { 'allExtensions': true, 'isTSX': true }]
        ]
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: my guess is: The modulesFromFile option tells webpack to not bundle any dependencies it finds in your package.json. Hence, your mgt-shared will not be processed by webpack but instead be left as a require('mgt-shared'). As this is a typescript module, node subsequently fails to require it. (Same goes for any other modules that need to be transpiled to be understood by your current node version)

Comment: Hey MarcRo I think that was it. I added that package to the whitelist and it seems to be getting past that now (or breaking on something else). It's now having problems with our files inside of directory but not in `src`.

Comment: You will need to be a little more specific on the new problem.-) Error-output might help. Also not clear what directory you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there was a way to whitelist other directories.

I needed to add the `whitelist` key to the options for `nodeExternals` like so:

```
  externals: [nodeExternals({
    whitelist: [/mgt-shared/],
    modulesFromFile: true
  })],
```

Everything else was able to stay the same.